# Rearranging data from tibble into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tibble in R arranged like this (just the first 20 rows of thousands):

A tibble: 20 × 4

|  | TF | confidence | target | mor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ahr | B | Cyp1a1 | 1 |
| 2 | Ahr | B | Cyp1a2 | 1 |
| 3 | Ahr | B | Cyp1b1 | 1 |
| 4 | Ahr | B | Fos | 1 |
| 5 | Ahr | B | Myc | 1 |
| 6 | Ahr | B | Ugt1a7c | 1 |
| 7 | Ahr | B | Ugt1a6a | 1 |
| 8 | Ahr | B | Ugt1a6b | 1 |
| 9 | Ahr | B | Asap1 | 1 |
| 10 | Ahr | B | Erg | 1 |
| 11 | Ahr | B | Vgll4 | 1 |
| 12 | Ar | A | Abce1 | 1 |
| 13 | Ar | A | Acad12 | 1 |
| 14 | Ar | A | Acad10 | 1 |
| 15 | Ar | A | Ahsg | 1 |
| 16 | Ar | A | Akr1b3 | 1 |
| 17 | Ar | A | Akt1 | 1 |
| 18 | Ar | A | Anapc10 | 1 |
| 19 | Ar | A | Ap2m1 | 1 |
| 20 | Ar | A | Appbp2 | 1 |

and I want to arrange it to look like this:

| TF | Description | Targets |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ahr | None | Cyp1a1 | Cyp1a2 | Cyp1b1 | Fos | Myc | Ugt1a7c | Ugt1a6a | Ugt1a6b | Asap1 | Erg | Vgll4 |
| Ar | None | Abce1 | Acad12 | Acad10 | Ahsg | Akr1b3 | Akr1b3 | Akt1 | Anapc10 | Ap2m1 | Appbp2 |  |

...The table goes on for thousands of lines. There can be a varying number of targets for a given TF value. How do I create this second table as a dataframe in R given the first table?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(TF) %>% 
  summarise(Targets = list(target))

#>    TF                                                                        Targets
#> 1 Ahr Cyp1a1, Cyp1a2, Cyp1b1, Fos, Myc, Ugt1a7c, Ugt1a6a, Ugt1a6b, Asap1, Erg, Vgll4
#> 2  Ar              Abce1, Acad12, Acad10, Ahsg, Akr1b3, Akt1, Anapc10, Ap2m1, Appbp2
```

This results in a so-called list-column (`Targets` is a list of character vectors), that will work for varying numbers of targets per TF.

---

With data:

```
df <- read.table(text =
'TF confidence  target  mor
Ahr B   Cyp1a1  1
Ahr B   Cyp1a2  1
Ahr B   Cyp1b1  1
Ahr B   Fos 1
Ahr B   Myc 1
Ahr B   Ugt1a7c 1
Ahr B   Ugt1a6a 1
Ahr B   Ugt1a6b 1
Ahr B   Asap1   1
Ahr B   Erg 1
Ahr B   Vgll4   1
Ar  A   Abce1   1
Ar  A   Acad12  1
Ar  A   Acad10  1
Ar  A   Ahsg    1
Ar  A   Akr1b3  1
Ar  A   Akt1    1
Ar  A   Anapc10 1
Ar  A   Ap2m1   1
Ar  A   Appbp2  1',
header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was just what I was looking for. How do I covert this output into a dataframe?

Comment: It's already a data frame. If you want to strip the `tibble` class, you can pass it through `as.data.frame`

Comment: Awesome! Works great, thanks!